# Capture output from adb logcat

Tags: android, python, selenium, adb, logcat

I am automating an Android application and I need to be able to capture logs while I am running the automation tests. I have tried using a terminal emulator but this only seems to give console logs. Next I tried using

```
        log = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "logcat"])
```

But when I do this my automation script stops indefinitely (presumably because it is waiting to continue after the logcat capture is complete), which does not work for me because I need the logcat to run in the background, while my script is running. So maybe 'Popen' is the way to go, and then pipe the output? Thank you!

Comment: Do you use the real time logcat output or do you just need it for later?

Comment: Need it for later. Would like to save outputs to a file and store in a folder.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Do you have any idea to capture the log realtime while running the test ?

Comment: I need to read the log realtime because I want to auto click base on the keyword base on the log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logs are always "running in the background", it's just whether you're looking at them. I would suggest instead, when you need a log dump, using

```
adb logcat -d
```

which will dump what it currently has, then exit.

So at the start of your test run:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('adb logcat -c'))
```

to clear the logs.

So at the end (and before any restart), dump the logs:

```
log = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('adb logcat -d'))
with open("loggy.file", "w") as f:
    f.write(log)
```

Comment: Ok, so I can run that at the end of the process I want to capture and it will dump all logs captured since the last dump? Also, how would I go about handling the output?

Comment: Because I will be using check_output

Comment: `adb logcat -d` dumps the entire log since last reboot. If you want to only include the logs during your test, start your test with `adb logcat -c` which clears the log, so then it will only contain the log you want. Dump it to a file.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a shot.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks again!